Entity has relationship with a second entity and with bridge entity between both entities
I am pretty new to Database design and I wish to know if the following design is accepted.
As you can see in my ER Diagram, the Museum entity has a relationship of one-to-many with the Guard, as many guards can be hired for a museum and a one-to-many relationship with the Cleaner. The bridge entity Guarding between Museum and Guard has a relationship of many-to-one with Museum and many-to-one with Guard. Am I allowed to have both a relationship between the Guard and Museum and a bridge entity between them?


Is it impossible that a guard or a cleaner works at more than one museum? If not, you need many-to-many relationships there. -- That said, technically your model is fine (in particular, considering the directed graph, there are no instance/record-level cycles), just why do you have a one-to-many relationship from Museum to Guards as well as a many-to-many via the bridge table? What does that second relationship represent?

Yes you are allowed.
But then ask yourself why?
Why do I need a specific FK to museum on the guard... Is the Guard somehow defined by that museum?  In this case, I think you will find that, no, the guard is a separate thing than the museum, and does not depend upon a museum for his existence.  So to properly normalize, you would not include museum on the guard.
Then look at the Guarding table.  What did I intend when placing museum_id directly on the guard, was it to indicate some kind of home base, or hiring museum, or most frequently worked at museum?  all of these can be captured with a new column on Guarding like relationship_type where you can specify the relationship between the guard and the museum.
finally, some guard may switch to new museums etc, so you should have some dates when the guarding relationship is valid - like a start_date and End_date to capture when this guard worked at this museum.
finally, why not go through the same thought process for cleaners?  you'll find that they also should have a linking class.
then still more - why aren't these two related things just people or employees with a column that indicates their job title?
anyhow - you're on the right track..

thank you very much for your answer! My thought process was that the Guard is hired at the respective museum, and as there would be more records for the Museum entity, the Guard should have a foreign key museum_id so we keep track of which museum he works at. But now, I understand that the bridge entity Guarding was more than enough for this as it shows the fact that Guard is working at the respective Museum. Cleaner also has a Cleaning birdge entity in my original database and I should remove the foreign key from it too as it is in the same situation as the Guard.

I have one more question, @Randy, is it wrong to keep the Guard and the Cleaner as two different, independent entities and not include them in a Supertype as subtypes? Does this affect the normalization?

my preference would be to just make these 'PERSON' records, then the same person can  even switch jobs from say a cleaner to a guard at some point - so PERSON with ORGANIZATION and PERSON-ORGANIZATION as a bridge covers all possible job titles and dates and times.  Thats a pretty optimal normalization.. Switching MUSEUM to ORGANIZATION also gives you vastly greater flexibility in case you want to know things like what cleaning company does the person also work for etc.

I see, thank you. But in this case, I specifically need to build a database for a museum.

Yes - a MUSEUM is one type of Organization...  anyway, I find general solutions a bit nicer than specific ones...

There can be many -- and I mean many -- relationships between each pair of entities. There's no limitation at all, where each relationship has its own specific meaning. This also includes reflexive relationships -- the ones that happen between an entity and itself.
Now, that can be also combined with indirect relationships between each pair of entities, something that is also not limited.
Therefore, you can have unlimited number of direct and indirect relationships between each pair of tables as well. Just make sure you understand the semantics of each entity and of each relationship.
